Why getsockopt with SO_SNDBUF for a TCP socket gives a 1/13 of the value at /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_default?
While doing some exercises about sockets, I wrote the code below.
    const int socketfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    int tcprcvbuf;
    socklen_t tcprcvbuflen = sizeof(tcprcvbuf);
      
    getsockopt(socketfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDBUF, &tcprcvbuf, &tcprcvbuflen);
    printf("Default send buffer (TCP): %d\n", tcprcvbuf);

The output is:
Default send buffer (TCP): 16384
While the result for cat /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_default is 212992, 13 times greater than 16384.
According to socket(7) man pages:

SO_SNDBUF
Sets  or  gets the maximum socket send buffer in bytes.  The kernel doubles this value (to allow space for bookkeeping overhead)
when it is set using setsockopt(2), and this doubled value is returned by getsockopt(2).   The  default  value  is  set  by  the
/proc/sys/net/core/wmem_default  file and the maximum allowed value is set by the /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max file.  The minimum
(doubled) value for this option is 2048

While playing around with setsockopt with the same params I noticed that setting any value below 2304 will give me 4608 (the double, as expected). Any value above it will give me the expected double of it. But the manual says the minimum (doubled) value would be 2048.
What am I missing here?

core/[rw]mem_default affects both TCP and UDP. Look at cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_?mem for the second fields in "min def max" output which supersede common settings in case of TCP

@yvs2014 I think that's good enough to make an answer out of. My /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_wmem shows 16384 for the def field.

details about overwritting the global generics are described on tcp(7) page (/ tcp_wmem) and udp(7) (/proc interfaces) correspondently

@yvs2014 Yep, there was it. In fact, if I just had searched for SO_SNDBUF on tcp(7) I would have found this.
Agreed with TedLyngmo. You should post it as an answer so I could accept it as such.
